# Python - ETFs Daily Data Web Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, finance

I'm trying to web scrape some daily info of differents ETFs. I found that https://www.marketwatch.com/ have a accurate info. The most relevant info is the open Price, outstanding shares, NAV, total assets of the ETF. Here is the link for IVV US Equity: https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/ivv

I'm just starting to get Python experience, would like to recieve some tips and guidelines on how to start a web scraping program. I have been told BeutifulSoup is the package to use for web scraping.

I have web scraped with VBA before but the HTML of the pages I had used are different, I don't know if this is because some values of the ETFs (such as Price and Taded Volume) change constantly.

I am open to any suggestion or any other website that could be useful (I have tried with Yahoo Finance and Morningstar and I get the same problema with the HTML code).

Comment: Hi, APIs are the best way to scrape the data, which changes every second like share market, youtube(view count, subscribers), Twitter, Facebook etc.,

Comment: Thanks Bhanu Tez, I will look for one that can help me with markets info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I agree that Beautiful Soup is a good approach. Here is some Python code which uses the Beautiful Soup library to extract the intraday price from the IVV fund page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/ivv")
html = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

if soup.h1.string == "Pardon Our Interruption...":
    print("They detected we are a bot. We hit a captcha.")
else:
    price = soup.find("h3", class_="intraday__price").find("bg-quote").string
    print(price)
```

The fact that the price changes frequently is not a problem. The names and classes of the HTML tags will remain constant. And this is all you need for Beautiful Soup to work.

Your main challenge is that the website is able to detect you are not using an Internet browser, and will display a captcha to your Python script. So you will need to find a method around this. Also, I recommend checking the legality of scraping and whether it violates their terms of service.

You can learn more about Beautiful Soup here:

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 2):

If you use the package [investpy](https://investpy.readthedocs.io/) you don't have to use web scraping to get the required data. investpy allows you to get daily ETF data. It also helps you to find an ETF by its ISIN (International Securities Identification Number):

```
investpy.search_etfs(by="isin", value="my_isin")
```

And that's the way you get the data:

```
investpy.get_etf_recent_data(etf=etf_name, country="my_country")
```