# Beautiful soup scraping for a variable that isnt coming up first

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

As per [Python - ETFs Daily Data Web Scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52978037/python-etfs-daily-data-web-scraping) I tried scraping for expense ratio.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/ivv").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

if soup.h1.string == "Pardon Our Interruption...":
    print("They detected we are a bot. We hit a captcha.")
else:
    price = soup.find("li", class_="kv__item").find("span").string

    print(price)
```

However this returns result for `open`. How can I tell it to take the 10th `li` and not the first one as it is returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [find_all()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)

```
price = soup.find_all("li", class_="kv__item")[9].find("span").string
```

Comment: Ah. Interesting, thank you! I tried applying it to the actual company website https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239726/ishares-core-sp-500-etf using `soup.find_all("li", class_="feeData")[1].find("span").string` but it is giving me `IndexError: list index out of range`. Any ideas?

Comment: `soup.find("li", class_="feeData").find("span").string` returns "Fees as stated in the prospectus" which is the wrong thing

Comment: @user8834780 There is only one li with that class in the page source. find_all(...)[1] is looking for the second element. Index starts at 0.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, in that case how can I get the second `span` for that only `li` class?

Comment: @user8834780 soup.find("li", class_="feeData").find_all("span")[1].string

Comment: Interestingly, it returns "None". Any idea why?

Comment: @user8834780 Just use price = soup.find("li", class_="feeData").find_all("span")[1].text

Comment: @user8834780 If a tag contains more than one thing, .string is defined to be None. In those cases use .text

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

With the lastest bs4 you can definitely use css [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) selector

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/ivv").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

if soup.h1.string == "Pardon Our Interruption...":
    print("They detected we are a bot. We hit a captcha.")
else:
    price = soup.select_one('.list--kv li:nth-of-type(10) span').string
    print(price)
```

---

You can even shorten the selector to:

```
li:nth-of-type(10) span
```

---

For list of spans within li:

```
.list--kv li span
```

Comment: You can then use same syntax to specify different li positions.

Comment: Thank you this is really cool. is there a way to define selector for `span` as well?

Comment: what  do you mean please? You can repeat nth-of-type for span e.g. span:nth-of-type(2) ....... Also, I thought you wanted just that one value? find_all retrieves all as opposed to targeting a specific by position.

Comment: Apologies, I am trying to make this a learning lesson. I was asking how would I handle a different case where there are multiple `li` AND multiple `span`

Comment: then remove the nth-of-type selector potentially and just use .list--kv li span